# Retrieve one value from database - ADO.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm getting the following error at the point of my `ExecuteScalar` command:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'GU1'

Code is below. The table is called `Outcodes`, column 1 is `Outcode` and column 2 is `Postcode`. I'm trying to return the outcode value where postcode = GU1. I'm not sure why it is looking for GU1 as a column name rather than a value within the column? Am I being silly? Any help greatly appreciated - really stuck with this one!

```
String sqlpostcodetooutcode = "select outcode from Outcodes where postcode = GU1";
SqlCommand sqlcompostcodettooutcode = new SqlCommand(sqlpostcodetooutcode, con);

con.Open();

try
{
     Object outcode = sqlcompostcodettooutcode.ExecuteScalar();
     String Outcode = outcode.ToString();
     Response.Write(Outcode);
}
catch { }
finally
{
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: `"SELECT outcode FROM Outcodes WHERE postcode = 'GU1'"`  Note the single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing single quotes (') around GU1 in your query

Comment: Thanks both! So much time wasted over such a simple mistake!